# Remove an table item from local storage with buttonclick

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, so I hope I can provide enough information about my problem. I am a beginner in coding.

For an exercise in the course I'm taking,  I have to build a web application. I am trying to build a web application on where the user can track his income and expenses. I'm at the point where the app is able to add income/expenses, and use that data for further purposes, but now I'm facing a problem in deleting the data.

The way the data is stored in local storage is like this (trough an onclick function):
`

```
const addBtn = document.getElementById('submit-button');
addBtn.onclick = function addTransaction() {
    let amountNow = amountInput.value;
    let inOutNow = inOutInput.value;
    let categoryNow = categoryInput.value;
    let transactions = localStorage.getItem('transactions');
    let transactionObj = [];

    if (transactions) {
        transactionObj = JSON.parse(transactions);
    }

    if (amountNow == "" || amountNow == 0 || inOutNow == "invalid" || categoryNow == "invalid") {
        alert('This input is not valid. Please check if the fields are filled in correctly.');
    } else {
        transactionObj.push({ "amount": amountNow, "inOut": inOutNow, "category": categoryNow, "month": month, "year": year });
        localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify(transactionObj));
    }
}
```

`
With adding the data like this I get the result I want, an array with objects. This array is displayed on my page in a table trough a foreach loop. Every row of this table has a deletebutton. When the user clicks one of those deletebuttons, that specific row, with its specific data, has to be removed from the local storage, but I have no clue how to do that.

I hope you guys can help me out here.

I have tried to delete data from the local storage trough an event listener, but I didn't manage to target the specific data.
I managed to delete a row from the table, but on a page-refresh, the row re-appeared, because of the foreach loop. The data was not deleted from the local storage this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm quite understanding what is going on here but from what it looks like you seem to be adding an object to an array and then putting it in local storage, I had a problem myself earlier when trying to remove an object from an array and this is the solution I found:

If you know what it's index is (an example is when you look something up in the array you would do `array[0]` and 0 is the index) you should be able to use the splice function (example: `array.splice(0, 1);`, 1 is the amount after the index it should remove). And then you just rewrite it to local storage and take it off of the table.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is find index of the obj you want to remove and then remove it from the array

```
let amountNow = amountInput.value;
let inOutNow = inOutInput.value;
let categoryNow = categoryInput.value;


let objToRemove = { "amount": amountNow, "inOut": inOutNow, "category": categoryNow, "month": month, "year": year }

let transactions = localStorage.getItem('transactions');
let transactionObj = [];

if (!transactions) {
 alert('list is empty');
 return;
}

transactionObj = JSON.parse(transactions);

// will return boolean
isObjSame(obj1,obj2)
{
  if(obj1.amount != abj2.amount) return false
  if(obj1.inOut != abj2.inOut) return false
  if(obj1.category != abj2.category) return false
  if(obj1.month != abj2.month) return false
  if(obj1.year != abj2.year) return false
  return true
 }

 // will find index of objToRemove
 // if obj is not in array, index will be -1
 index = transactionObj.findIndex((obj)=>{
   return isObjSame(objToRemove, obj);
 });

 if(index < 1)
 {
   alert('item is not there in the list');
   return;
 }

// 1 because want to remove 1 obj
transactionObj.splice(index,1);

localStorage.setItem('transactions',JSON.stringify(transactionObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your object assign an id to that obj as well as to that created html like 001,002, or could use some library for that or you can use `new Date().getTime().toString()` create one(personally i recommand using some library).

Either select all the table rows using querySeletorAll or use event delegation or whatever you prefer And listen for click event on rows to select the assign id, get that id look for that in localStorage using loop or array filter method if id matches don't push that into the new Array, then update the localStorage with that new Array and remove the row from table